# Is asking for technical support okay?

Tags: discussion, scope

A friend of mine has a problem with some Windows shenanigans, with a particular BSOD error and a driver. (We've all been there)

Is SuperUser the appropriate forum to ask for a solution/answer/explanation to an end-user, general computer support problem?

If not, what would be?

Comment: It could be useful to read the "[How to ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)" page before posting any computer support-type questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly on-topic for Super User.

Comment: While I agree that this is technically "on-topic", this is a fine line to be tread.  Coming in with a question that hasn't been research all that well, can turn into a very lengthy back and forth chat that really doesn't benefit anyone except the original person, and turns the question more into a forum.

Comment: I agree it's on-topic and can stay, as long as the poster spends some time trying to figure it out and shares what they've tried already.  I'm getting bored of questions like "My computer does X, what could be wrong?  How do I diagnose it?", with no sign of trying anything, or even an attempt to have a basic understanding of their own problem.  Many days I feel like "SuperUser" has turned into "Free Tech Support For The Lazy End-User". But hey, that's probably just me. :) /rant

Comment: I say as long as the question/answer is oriented towards a precise problem/symptom and that the thread becomes useful as a reference for others that stumble upon the same thing again.